strange sporadic bugs in the most trivial C program involving pthreads
Below is the C source code for a trivial program.
The program has a main loop where the user is asked to choose between 3 options:
1- print some text
2- do some work (with no side effects)
3- exit the program.
If the user chooses 2, then a function is called (named shenanigans) that represents a computationally expensive, parallelizable problem. This function makes use of pthreads to take advantage of multi-core CPU architecture, however note that the "shenanigans" function makes sure to "join" every created thread, and does not return until all of the worker threads have finished.
The multi-threaded nature of the "shenanigans" function should be completely transparent to the rest of the program.
here is the source code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int convert_to_integer(const char *str, int *outValue) {
    if (str == NULL || outValue == NULL) return -1; // NULL pointer error

    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;
    long temp = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);

    if (errno == ERANGE && (temp == LONG_MAX || temp == LONG_MIN))
        return -2; // Overflow or underflow
    if (errno != 0 && temp == 0)
        return -3; // Other conversion error
    if (endptr == str)
        return -4; // No digits were found
    if (*endptr != '\0')
        return -5; // Additional characters after number
    if (temp > INT_MAX || temp < INT_MIN)
        return -6; // Value out of int range

    *outValue = (int)temp;
    return 0; // Success
}


int get_int_from_stdin(int *target) {
    if (target == NULL) return -1; // NULL pointer error

    char input[64];
    if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL)
        return -2; // Reading error or EOF

    // null-terminate the string if newline is found
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    if (input[len - 1] == '\n') {
        input[len - 1] = '\0';
    } else {
        // Clear stdin buffer if input exceeded buffer length, to avoid leftover input affecting subsequent reads
        int ch;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
        if (len == sizeof(input) - 1) return -3; // Input too long
    }

    int value;
    int result = convert_to_integer(input, &value);
    if (result != 0) return result; // Propagate error code from conversion

    *target = value;
    return 0; // Success
}


void * thread_function(void * args) {
    // this is work that will be done by threads
    // notice there is no side effects and no interaction with 
    // stdout and stdin 
    // just waste a bunch of time
    long x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
            if (i %2 == 0) x++;
            else x--;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

void shenanigans(){
    // run 7 different worker threads in parallel
    printf("running tasks in parallel\n");
    fflush(stdout); // flushing the output buffer doesn't do anything
    //---- start of multithreading code
    pthread_t threads[7];
    
    // initiate 7 worker threads to do some work
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, thread_function, NULL);

    // wait for all threads to finish
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);
    // ---- end of multithreading code
    printf("task finished...\n");
}

void print_junk(){
    printf("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n");
}

int main() {
    while (1) {
        printf("\nChoose an option from the following menu: \n");
        printf("1- do some calculations\n");
        printf("2- print some junk to standard output\n");
        printf("3- exit...\n");
        int choice;
        int result = get_int_from_stdin(&choice);
        if (result != 0) {
            printf("Invalid input, try again\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (choice == 1) {
            // this function uses parallelism to get its job done faster
            // but the parallelism ought to be completely transparent to the main function
            shenanigans();
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            print_junk();
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid choice, try again\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


When I compile and execute this code, I get some strange sporadic bugs:
1-
In the main loop, when the user enters option "1", I expect the line "running tasks in parallel" to show up on the console immediately, before the main thread blocks to wait for the worker threads to finish. However this is not always the case. Many a times after I enter "1" to the console, the program becomes unresponsive as worker threads do their work and only after some time has passed do I see "running tasks in parallel" get printed on the console
2- for some strange reason, it seems that when the main thread is waiting for the worker threads to finish there are some characters being pushed onto the input buffer, causing bad side effects in the main loop when I attempt to read the user's choice.
here is a picture describing the issues I'm referring to

These race condition bugs are most strange because:
1- there is ZERO input and output in the worker threads.
2- there is ZERO shared memory or mutation of global state between threads
What am I missing here?
EDIT:
the issue was environment related. I was using Oracle VirtualBox to host a debian linux virtual machine.
I set up another debian linux environment using VMware workstation and I no longer have this problem.
Thank you for all who helped

OT: The end of get_int_from_stdin could be replaced by a simple return convert_to_integer(input, target);

The optimizer might eliminate the body of thread_function() since there are no observable side-effects in the looping code.  That shouldn't have any real effect on the code except that the threads may not take as long as you expect.

@JonathanLeffler That is fair, but compiling with gcc does not optimize to get rid of code.

As for your problem, is you Enter key working as expected? Does it sometimes glitch? Is something holding it down? Remember to check the Enter key on the numeric keypad as well. Do you have some program running in the background that might insert Enter key-presses?

@Someprogrammerdude that is a reasonable suspicion to have, it looks like I'm inserting newlines doesn't it? I can guarantee you that is not a problem.

Also OT: You don't need to remove the newline in the input you get from fgets. You could instead add a check in the conversion function to check for *endptr != '\n' and return that as a failure.

Are you perhaps running this inside an IDE? The I/O windows that IDEs provide frequently have a variety of quirks.  They don't necessarily act like real interactive devices.  I ask this in part because I do not reproduce the behavior you describe, and in part because I don't see any reason to expect to do.

@JohnBollinger good question. I do use VS code, but I get the same wrong buggy behaviour when I use the standard GNOME terminal with debian linux. I am using a virtual machine for what its worth.

Well, any way around, I do not reproduce the behavior you describe.  In half a dozen tries, the "running tasks in parallel" message was always printed immediately after I entered option 1.  And that's indeed what I would expect, since you fflush the output before creating any additional threads, much less wait for them, and they don't do any I/O anyway.  Something is strange about your environment.  Possibly it is related to running in a VM, though I would not have expected that.

@JohnBollinger thank for your taking the time to attempt to reproduce the issue. while the problem does not occur literally with each iteration of the infinite loop in the main program, I can say it is very easy to reproduce on my end. I don't have a machine right now that runs a POSIX compliant operating system natively. I am using Oracle VMware Virtualbox inside Windows. perhaps that could be related. again, thank you for taking the time to compile and run it. are you running Linux or mac natively?

"Many a times after I enter "1" to the console, the program becomes unresponsive as worker threads do their work and only after some time has passed do I see "running tasks in parallel" get printed on the console" - Are you perhaps running the program from within some IDE? If so, try running it directly from the command line.

Not reproductible. I tried several times on macOS with no such observable effect.

Did you compile as ISO C or as C99 or older?

@TedLyngmo I tried both VS code and Gnome Terminal (debian linux, bash shell) with the same results

@Lundin I tried both c99 and c11 with identical results.
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic  example.c

Not a direct answer as to why, but some ideas to prevent problems.
If errno is not instantiated per thread:

As code is converting to an int, call strto...() that is more likely wider than an int like strtoimax().  With a wider than int type, no need to play with errno and deal with any possible thread issues.

After strto...(str, &endptr, 10) call, use int my_errno = errno; to reduce any errno change window and use my_errno afterword.




Avoid potential UB if the first character read was a null character.

    size_t len = strlen(input);
    //if (input[len - 1] == '\n') {
    //   input[len - 1] = '\0';

    if (len > 0 && input[len - 1] == '\n') {
        input[len - 1] = '\0';



Simplify

    //if (errno == ERANGE && (temp == LONG_MAX || temp == LONG_MIN))
    //    return -2; // Overflow or underflow
    //if (errno != 0 && temp == 0)
    //    return -3; // Other conversion error

    if (errno == ERANGE)
        return -2; // Overflow or underflow
    if (errno != 0)
        return -3; // Other conversion error


Change priority

if (endptr == str) should be the first test.  This improves consistency across implementations as Some set errno in this case.

This might explain things.

Avoid uninitialized value of int choice;

Use int choice = -1; as get_int_from_stdin(&choice); may not set choice.

"use int my_errno = errno; to reduce any errno change window" The compiler might be too smart/dumb to understand the purpose of that code and optimize out my_errno entirely. It might have to be declared volatile to block such optimizations from happening. Now of course the root problem is that errno is used in the first place, it's ancient Unix crap from a time before multi-threading existed, which should never have made it into the C standard to begin with. We can do error handling of strtol without using errno and that's the actual recommended practice here.

errno should have _Thread_local storage duration at least from C11 and beyond though.

Some very good points, especially #3. But none related to the elusive bug I'm seeing.
note that #6 is a non problem because I only read the choice variable if and only if the get_int_from_stdin function returns with a success flag.

@Lundin "We can do error handling of strtol without using errno and that's the actual recommended practice here." --> how to detect out of range problems, use a wider type?

@chux-ReinstateMonica What I meant is that the exact cause of the error is probably not all that interesting in most scenarios, as long as it gets detected. And if you insist on detecting it, you are at a point in the program where performance no longer matter, so you could as well manually implement that error check at that point. A little loop with isdigit examining how long the sequence of digit is etc. Not hard to code.
